# Integration of exponential function (problem below):

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

[image]

I have tried u substitution, but I'm not really sure what to do.

This is what I tried:

$u = x^3 - 2x^2 + x + 7\\
du = (3x^2-4x+1)dx$

But I'm not sure what to do now.

I also tried:

$u = 2x-1\\
du = 2dx$

Comment: Have you tried integrating by parts to reduce the power on the polynomial factor?

Comment: ok i'll try that! How did u know to integrate by parts? @user170231

Comment: These days it amounts to pattern recognition, but I remember first learning about IBP for integrands like $xe^x$ and $x^2e^x$, so I figured it should work pretty well in this case.

Comment: @user170231 what is the pattern recognition? I know for u sub I look for if the derivative of a u will replace the other part, but I don't know what to look for for integration by parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to help:

Get $e^{-1}$
from the integral,
so you just have
$e^{-2x}$.

Use IBP to get
$\int x^{n+1}e^{-x}$
in terms of
$\int x^{n}e^{-x}$
and 
$x^{n+1}e^{-x}$.
And, of course,
$\int e^{-x} dx
= -e^{-x}
$.